# Unable to map ctrl-l

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, microsoft-windows

My _vimrc contains the following lines:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin


nmap <c-l> :w<CR>

nmap <c-m> :w<CR>
```

I try to map <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to `:w`, and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> is the control group.

I open a new file, press `ctrl-m`, the file saves. I press `ctrl-l`, the command line shows `:update`. I press `ctrl-shift-l`, the file saves.

[image]
The figure shows the UI after I press `ctrl-l`. The cursor was on the previous line.

[image]
I run `:map` , `<C-L>` is registered, but I can only trigger it with `ctrl-shift-l`.

Why does the mapping of `ctrl-l` fail?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise use `nnoremap` not `nmap`.  What do you see in Insert mode when you type `ctrl-q` followed by `ctrl-l`?